# "bad packing" notification in xcode console

Tags: ios8, xcode6

After switching to xcode 6 I began to receive this notification in the console when running my app on iOS8 iphone simulator or real device.

What I see in my log after i receive some data from forecast server is something like this:

```
2014-09-22 16:51:20.159 MyApp[44700:1507801] {
cloudiness = 3;
dayTime = 2;
precipitation = 10;
status = 1;
temperature = 16;
}
bad packing
bad packing
```

Does anyone have a clue where to search for a process that could send that "bad packing" message?

Comment: I get this too. Do you use AFNetworking?

Comment: @NicHubbard Yes i use it. Actually i use RestKit that uses AFNetworking

Comment: I am wondering if this is the issue. Because I am getting that error when I am using `AFNetworking` to lazy load `UIImageView`.

Comment: I am getting it with a PDF-based app.  I've never heard of AFNetworking, and the app does not access the web at all.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this message is printed when calling `[UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:cache:]` function.

It could be some other image loading function.
(I found this by adding Symbolic Breakpoint - "puts" function.)

It seems that some information of JPEG image is invalid or Apple's image decoder does not handle correctly.

I think this problem could be ignored if everything works fine.

Anyway, when I re-saved all images using other image editor, this message is disappeared.

Comment: Same issue here with certain downloaded images, thank you for the breakpoint info.